# how to find a number in hierarchical list

Tags: python, arrays, search, python-2.7, recursion

i have a hierarchical list in python, hierarchical in sense a list contains a number of lists but the number and length of sub child lists are not defined.

```
[[5], [[1], [[2, 3], [4]]]]
```

I am trying to do find a number in the following way, but function returns nothing, is there a pythonic way to find it?

```
def is_present(lst,value):
      for element in lst:
          if isinstance(element, list):
              return is_present(element,value)
          else:
              if value == element:
              return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [14]: %paste
def isPresent(L, val):
  if val in L:
    return True
  else:
    return any(isPresent(i,val) for i in L if isinstance(i, list))

## -- End pasted text --

In [15]: L = [[5], [[1], [[2, 3], [4]]]]

In [16]: isPresent(L, 1
   ....: )
Out[16]: True

In [17]: isPresent(L, 2)
Out[17]: True

In [18]: isPresent(L, 3)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: isPresent(L, 4)
Out[19]: True

In [20]: isPresent(L, 5)
Out[20]: True

In [21]: isPresent(L, 6)
Out[21]: False
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few problems:

1. Your indentation on the line for your return statement is incorrect.
2. You never return `False` anywhere (if the element isn't in the list).
3. When recursing, you should only return `True` if the recursion returns `True` (and ignore `False` returns from the recursion). This makes sure the list continues to be checked even if a recursion doesn't find the element.

The following is your function with those problems fixed:

```
def is_present(lst,value):
    for element in lst:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            if is_present(element,value):
                return True
        else:
            if value == element:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: it returns false when i pass the same list and 4 as parameters

Comment: @Dani: sorry, my mistake. A further correction is required - see edited answer.